# Transforming and tidying nested data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains columns of nested data frames. The structure is as follows:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id        : chr  "001" "002"
 $ name      : chr  "a" "b"
 $ nestedList:List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ val1: num  100 101 102
  .. ..$ val2: num  200 201 202
  .. ..$ val3: num  300 301 302
  ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ val1: num  1000 1001
  .. ..$ val2: num  2000 2001
  .. ..$ val3: num  3000 3001
```

It can be recreated with the following code:

```
myNestedDataFrame <- data.frame(id = c("001", "002"), name = c("a", "b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myNestedDataFrame$nestedList[[1]] <- data.frame(val1 = c(100, 101, 102), val2 = c(200, 201, 202), val3 = c(300, 301, 302))
myNestedDataFrame$nestedList[[2]] <- data.frame(val1 = c(1000, 1001), val2 = c(2000, 2001), val3 = c(3000, 3001))
```

I am trying to get the data into the following form:

```
   id name val1 val2 val3
1 001    a  100  200  300
2 001    a  101  201  301
3 001    a  102  203  302
4 002    b 1000 2000 3000
5 002    b 1001 2001 3001
```

I have been able to achieve this using a convoluted series of loops and joins, but I can't help but think that there is a more elegant solution using apply or mapping functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `tidyr::unnest(myNestedDataFrame)`

Comment: In base, maybe `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(myNestedDataFrame, seq(nrow(myNestedDataFrame))), function(x){data.frame(x[-3], x[[3]], row.names = NULL)}))`

Comment: alistaire, thanks for the quick reply. Both of these achieve what I've been looking for.